# A Winter Day's Drive

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, affix-riddle

Another riddle from ~ *Words That Get Stuck In MacGyver88's Head* ~(:P)

> My prefix - ( i ) are this/these.
> My infix - The sixth lost its sixth.
> My suffix - Even though short, eating the first still leaves enough.
> My whole - A nice sight to see on a winter day's drive.
> What am I?

Hint 1

> ( i ) can be considered a rough representation of a logo or symbol

Hint 2

> My whole is probably not a word you hear outside of a certain college class or related profession. (It's been stuck in my head for 20 years)

Comment: I just upvoted your question, congrats on reaching more than 5000 rep! :D

Comment: I feel special :p

Comment: @Anonymus25-ReinstateMonica, Thank you.  I appreciate your generosity.  I did that once as well for someone's milestone.  It felt pretty good.  I hoped it helped them have a good Christmas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Supersaturation

My prefix - ( i ) are this/these.

> This is the symbol for [The Incredibles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Incredibles) who are **SUPER(S)**

My infix - The sixth lost its sixth.

> The sixth planet from the Sun is **SATURN**, without its sixth letter is **SATUR**

My suffix - Even though short, eating the first still leaves enough.

> I think this is **RATION** because eating the first ration still leaves enough food, even though it is in short supply.
>  **OP clarification:**  SATUR ends in R, RATION starts with R, eating the R is fine because R is already present in SATUR, so it involves the overlap.

My whole - A nice sight to see on a winter day's drive.

> I think the idea here is that supersaturation equates to more snow on the ground since it cannot be absorbed into it.
>  **OP clarification:** Supersaturation of the salt leaves salt crystals visible on the road, meaning the salt is left over and the roads should be dry.

Comment: This is correct. My intentions rot13(fnghe raqf va e, engvba fgnegf jvgu e, rngvat gur e vf svar orpnhfr e vf nyernql cerfrag va fnghe, fb vg vaibyirf gur bireync.)

Comment: rot13(fhcrefnghengvba bs gur fnyg yrnirf fnyg pelfgnyf ivfvoyr ba gur ebnq, zrnavat gur fnyg vf yrsg bire naq gur ebnqf fubhyq or qel.)

Comment: @MacGyver88 Ah, okay, thanks for the clarification, will edit in.

Comment: Nice work. I wondered where people were getting stuck.  I thought the ( i ) hint would speed things up.

Comment: @MacGyver88 Yeah, that's the bit that I got stuck with. I had figured out the rest but couldn't think what the prefix could be (I think the hint about it being a symbol/logo really helped).

Comment: I'm just glad I could get the word unstuck and sent to others that care.  My wife gets tired of hearing me talk like a scientist all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> SNOWFLAKE?

Because

> The prefix: Self explanatory, because SNOW and SNOWFLAKE are technically the same thing

> The infix: FLAK, taken away the sixth letter of the word SNOWFLAKE gives FAK, which explains the sixes, as the devils number. (If you still don't get it, it's the swearing F word. I'm not gonna say it, just to be safe from the Stack Exchange rules.)

> The suffix: The letter E is most definitely short, but cutting off the first part of the letter gives a 3 line pattern, in which the number 3 symbolises (questionably?) life and living forever, which is most definitely enough.

> The whole: SNOWFLAKEs are most definitely beautiful to see on a winter's day drive.

Comment: Sorry. Not the intended answer. Good try though.

Answer (score 1):

is it

> DROPLET

My prefix - ( i ) are this/these.

> drop are droplets

My suffix - Even though short, eating the first still leaves enough.

> -let basically means small or short

My whole - A nice sight to see on a winter day's drive.

> can be found on car windows in winter.

Comment: Sorry. Not the intended answer. Plus, your infix is missing.